# Position input checkboxes next to each other

Tags: html, css, checkbox, input

I am trying to create a list of 3 checkboxes and next to two of the checkboxes, I want a small checkbox to hide the specific property.

[image]

I just have a problem of position the checkboxes properly.

I guess it should be something like

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Property 1
      (
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">
          Hide
        </label>
      )
    </label>
  </li>
  (...)
</ul>
```

but maybe it is not good to place the hide checkbox inside the other checkbox-label, so maybe I should create a table, so the two checkboxes can be aligned next to each other.

Comment: You should definitely NOT create a `<table>`, because this has absolutely nothing to do with tabular data. What you can do, is contain each element inside a wrapper-container, either a `<span>` or a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

use style="display: inline-block;" inside of input tag